# $g(f(n))\in o(g(n)/n)$ for any $f(n)\in o(n)$

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(n)\in o(n)$. Is it always possible to find a function $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(f(n))\in o(g(n)/n)$?

I'm pretty sure that if we pick $g$ to be "large enough", we can do this. But I don't know how to formalize the argument.

(See the definition of $o$ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(n)\in o(n)$, hence $f(n)\leq n/h(n)$ for some function $h(n)\to +\infty$. Thus $h(n)\geq 2$  for any large $n$. Take $g(n)=e^n$: $g(f(n))\leq e^{n/2}\in o(e^n/n)$.